# Tish'a Asar Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred nineteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this week's Parsha

219 = טהרה

Comment: Is that tahaRA, tahoraH, or taHEIra?

Comment: Tahara...............

Comment: Would that be TAhorRAH or TAhoRAHH (Rashi 12:4)

Comment: Checkmark because it's not just stam a word from the parsha.

Answer (score 2):

Acc. to Rashi's timeline, there were 219 years from Yosef's pardon until the exodus.  (7+2+210)

Answer (score 2):

There were 219 years from Yosef's birth until the attempted exodus of the bnei Ephraim 30 years early.  (30+7+2+180)